# Where do I add a file to read from in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io, filereader

I have been trying to read a file into Eclipse. I've looked over other questions, but those answers did not remedy the situation (refreshing the project folder, using getProperty and specifying the correct path, etc.) I've moved the file into every folder and I get the same error. I've copied the file into the directory as shown here:

[image: directory]

I've also pasted the code below. It's stupidly simple. The error I get is "FileInputStream.open(String) line: not available [native method]".

Any help would be appreciated. Code is below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Modulo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File questions = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(questions);
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            String divide = sc.next();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(x % y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As per your program, the file `input.txt` must be at the path from where you run your java program.

Comment: You can use an absolute or relative path to point to your file. Something like `D:/Folder1/input.txt` or `/home/eypros/input.txt`. Mind the forward slash or use `\\` to escape in windows.

Comment: Doesn't Eclipse run it's Java programs within the context of the workspaces bin directory...I don't use Eclipse so I could be so off.  Try using `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` or `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());` in your code, which will print out where the program is currently running.  You could also use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to do the same thing...

Comment: @Eypros The poor OP is trying to do the right thing and not use absolute paths, it makes life so much easier if they can learn NOT to do that ;)

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/283423/Based on what you have included, my guess would be that the file 
 cannot be found

Comment: @MadProgrammer the right thing according to whom? He is trying to access a single file. If he wanted to access multiple files it wouldn't make sense to move all of them to the src folder!

Comment: @Eypros And it doesn't make sense to use an absolute file...ever...as this makes the program inflexible.  The fact that the OP's put the file in the `src` directory raises a multitude of other questions

Comment: The OP said `I've moved the file into every folder` which also raises some issues but anyway I cannot be a mind reader. I pointed out absolute path since it's more difficult to paste them wrongly. Relative path just fail if you don't know your root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copy that file into Project folder parallel to src. This is the place base path of your code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please check and revert.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends.

If you want the file to be embedded within your application when your deploy it (as a Jar file for example), then you can't use `File` to reference it, as you've tried to include it within your application.

Eclipse further complicates the matter, as you can't included resources within your `src` directory, but needs to be maintained within a `resources` directory at the same level as your `src` folder (this folder may need to be included as part of your build process, but I only have a passing knowledge of how Eclipse works)...

Once you've corrected for all this, you will then need to use `Class#getResource` to load the resource...for example...

```
try (InputStream is = Modulo.class.getResourceAsStream("/input.txt")) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
    //...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, if you want the file to be an external resource to your program, then you need to place it within a location relative to the location that the program is executed.

Normally, I would suggest the project directory, but I have a funny feeling that Eclipse run's it's Java programs in a different location ... and I don't know if you can change it...

In this case, you could use `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` or `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());` or `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` which will tell you where you program is currently running and place the file there.

Of course, once build (into a Jar) you would need to place the file within a context that was relative to the location it was executed from...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse by default looks for the file in the main project directory in your case `Remainders`, if your file is not there, you get an exception. Try placing the file directly under your project and run the same program, it should run correctly.